# P value adjustments when subsetting dataframe

Tags: anova, p-value, adjustment

I'm analysing a dataset that contains different species. I first use the species ID as an independent variable but then I have to analyse the dataset separated for the different species (in total 3). For each species I run an Anova with multiple parameters. How can I adjust the p values to account for this multiple testing? I know the Holm method but don't know what the number of comparisons is. The number of models I run (i.e. 3)? Or the number of models times the number of parameters (p values)? Can you help me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Run a linear regression all in one, no need for separate models.

Comment: I know this would be the best way but I was specifically asked to analyze the separately

Comment: In that case, the number of comparisons is the total number of hypothesis from all the models.

Comment: thanks, this means the number of all explanatory variables (after removing the insignificant ones) from all models I use?

Comment: No, this means the number of hypotheses tested in all the models. In ANOVA this happens to be the number of explanatory variables if you only include the variables (no interactions, polynomials, etc...). All the p-values which you get from all the models is the number of hypotheses.

Comment: ok, this means including the insignificant terms that I have removed from the models?

Comment: Yes, if you have tested some hypotheses which you later removed, you still need to account for them.